# How to update the Chrome browser on my desktop computer?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to update the Chrome browser on my desktop computer to work with the remote debugger on my Samsung Galaxy A 50 (which has version 116.05845.114)

On my  desktop computer with kubutu 20.04 I have  :

```
$ uname -a
Linux master-at-home 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/HRBrazy/affiliate$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
5.15.0-53-generic
x86_64
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/HRBrazy/affiliate$ dpkg -s    chromium-browser
Package: chromium-browser
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: oldlibs
Installed-Size: 161
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
Provides: gnome-www-browser, www-browser, x-www-browser
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Pre-Depends: debconf, snapd
Description: Transitional package - chromium-browser -> chromium snap
 This is a transitional dummy package. It can safely be removed.
 .
 chromium-browser is now replaced by the chromium snap.
Homepage: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/
```

Which commands have I to run on  my desktop computer to have the same versions of Chrome?

Comment: chrome != chromium-browser. if you mean "chrome" you download it https://www.google.com/chrome/ and use "software" to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Linux command line:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

That will install the latest Google Chrome browser and it will be updated by apt. Hope that helps.

Note this is for Google Chrome. NOT Chromium.

If you want chromium just use apt:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```